# Meteor Perfomance Issue

Tags: node.js, performance, meteor, publish-subscribe

We are using **meteor V1.5** in our project. We noticed a strange behavior with `publish` and `subscriber` method. Posting a screen shot from KADIRA for one of the `subscriber`
[image]

`publish` method

```
Meteor.publish( 'companyBuiltCourses', companyId => {  
    return BuiltCourses.find({ company_id: companyId })
});
```

When we use below `subscriber` and we visit `xyz` page, KADIRA shows continuous fetching of documents as shown in screen shot. **Even though we visit another page, this graph remains same**

```
Template.xyz.onCreated(function() {
   Tracker.autorun( () => {
     if (Meteor.user()) {
        Meteor.subscribe('companyBuiltCourses',Meteor.user().profile.company_id);
     }
   });
});
```

When we use below `subscriber` method and we visit `xyz` page, KADIRA shows continuous fetching of documents as shown in screen shot. **But when we visit another page, this graph goes down to 0. It won't fetch document anymore**

```
Template.xyz.onCreated(function() {
   this.autorun( () => {
     let self = this;
      if(Meteor.user()){
        self.subscribe('companyBuiltCourses',Meteor.user().profile.company_id);
     }
   });
});
```

**For development environment both methods fetch documents only once when required. This is the PRODUCTION issue.**

We are hosting MongoDB remotely and we run production on `pm2`. There should not be a continuous fetching I guess.

Comment: How large is your `BuiltCourses` collection? If it takes a long time to fetch data from server to client using publish/subscribe pattern, you should consider changing it to a server method.

Comment: Thanks for comment. No, It's not taking time to get data. I am only worrying about this continuous graph. It shoudn't be

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard to tell what is going on, as the code you provide is simple enough. The only thing I can think of, is that the tracker function is being called repeatedly. So the question is, what causes that?

This code: `Meteor.user().profile.company_id` suggests that you are storing data against the user's profile in the `user` collection. This isn't great, because the user can modify their own data from the console, and also the accounts system modifies the user record at times, which may affect how many times subscriptions fire. I would recommend storing the related data in a separate collection anyway, which can be keyed by `Meteor.userId()`. I'm not sure if that's the answer to this one.

Comment: Thanks Mikkel for pointing out security loop hole. My main concern is about that continuous graph. I am agree with you that tracker function is being called repeatedly somehow.